# Prices in one or separate MariaDB tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database, mariadb

I am working on a relational DB on MariaDB for a web application and I have a doubt about how to store the prices of products.

I have products, each of them from a different category (toys, dolls, videogames), and they are all stored in different tables. The attributes that are only related to themselves and not to the other tables are also stored on each category table.

Apart from that, some products share some features. For example some of the products are electrical, so there is an `electrical_features` table for those products and I simply used a table in the middle connecting the category table to the `electrical_features` creating a 1:N -> N:1 relationship.

Now, I store three different things about prices. `original_price`, `discount_price`, `discount_enddate`. I was thinking on storing it straight onto the category table, but just thinking it properly, wouldn't it make more sense to create a table just for the prices and connecting it to the other tables the same way I used for the `electrical_features` table?

I hope I explained myself properly. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: This is a design question. You should choose the table structure that best supports your business processes. Since we do not know anything about those, it is somewhat difficult to suggest a solution that is not based on an opinion only.

Answer (score 1):

> I have products, each of them from a different category (toys, dolls, videogames), and they are all stored in different tables.

No.  I would recommend that you have a single products table having among its columns a `productId` and the `categoryId` to which it belongs, e.g.

```
productId | categoryId | productName | categoryName | price
    1     |     1      | Monopoly    | toys         | 24.99
    2     |     2      | Barbie      | dolls        | 14.95
    3     |     3      | Warcraft    | video games  | 31.50
```

I only included a single price column but you can extend this to include a discount along with anything else you want.

As for features, since each product can have a variable number of features, and there may be many, it doesn't make sense to lop on more columns to the above table.  Instead, create a new `features` table which relates a `productId` to one or more features.  You can also define a category for the feature itself.

```
productId | featureId | featureCategory | fName    | fcName
    3     |     1     |        1        | video    | electrical
    3     |     2     |        1        | computer | electrical
    3     |     3     |        2        | game     | recreation
```

Comment: I see your point. Makes total sense. I am gonna give it a try and redo the schema. Will let you know how it looks after.

Comment: Just to offer a slight counter opinion... while I agree with the first half of this answer, and of the benefits of a "tags" table; I would not rule out additional details tables for specific, frequently used classes of products. It is hard to provide a specific example for your business, but in situations where it would be desirable to be able to compare similar products, the process would go much easier with fields specifically for common traits. (MPG for cars, disk size required for video games, recommended ages for toys and dolls, etc....) I'd also keep category names in a categories table.

Comment: @Uueerdo Agree that category name and other metadata should be normalized and put into a separate table.  I only listed it there for readability and to keep the answer relatively short.

Comment: @Uueerdo so if I get it right you are suggesting, as an example, that I could create a table for videogames with fields like disk_size, genre, minimum_age...), another table for cars with MPG, maximum_speed, color...) and another table for less common attributes that would work like a tag system. Right?

Comment: @ragtime.sp yep, though I am not positive I would classify the tag system as for "less common attributes", maybe "more general and/or optional attributes" would be a better description. For example, most things have one or more colors, but colors may not be relevant for all things; at the same time, in more specialized details it might matter what color a specific part of the item is. I'd put general color(s) in the "tags" table, and part color(s) in a specialized table. (In the case cars, people usually care about differentiating interior and exterior colors.)